# Restoring default viewer settings in texlipse

Tags: texlipse, eclipse

In Eclipse/Texlipse there are default viewer settings to help configure the viewer.

They can be found at `Window -> Preferences -> Texlipse -> Viewer Settings` .
[image: This image shows how one can navigate to the viewer settings.]

I deleted the other viewer settings in the past for no good reason.
I want to switch from AcroRead to Sumatra and i would like to load the default preset for that. How can i reimport those old settings?

---

EDIT:
Uninstalling Texlipse and reinstalling Texlipse did not change the result.

Comment: I went as far as reinstalling eclipse to solve this. I hope someone knows a better way.

Answer (score 1):

I can't help you with resetting that, although it usually is some preference file which probably resides in your .workspace.

However, here are my defaults

I use Sumatra as an external viewer, so the "viewer command" for me is empty. Obviously, you should adapt it to your install!

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing - i actually tried that. As a sidenote, the viewer command needs to be set after the input filename, otherwise it leads to errors. I can get it listed in the viewer settings until i close the preferences. After that all is lost and my changes are gone. I tried to modyfy the acrobat entrie to be a sumatra call, but that leads to nullpointer exceptions. my guess is something is wrong in the eclipse build, so i want to start from the default entries.

Comment: Did you try a different workspace?

Comment: Stupid question, but have you tried clicking on the "Restore Defaults" button?

Comment: I did. It does not bring the defaults back. If i delete the last viewer i can bring that single one back with this button. But it does not bring me near the desired outcome.

Comment: Note the latest CLI settings (preferred method) for SumatraPDF and latest eclipse 4.9 [are as per](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/393446/texlipse-sumatra-oxygen-windows-10-setup-cant-find-texlipse-jar-file?rq=1)