# Texlipse/Sumatra/Oxygen/Windows 10 setup -- can't find texlipse jar file

Tags: texlipse

Trying to get inverse search working with Texlipse and Sumatra with Eclipse
Oxygen(4.7.0) on Windows 10. Setup requires knowing where the texlipse plugin is located.
The only possibility I can see is 
"C:\Users\jon\eclipse\java-oxygen\eclipse\plugins" 
but there's no texlipse.jar file there. The only file there is an
"org.eclipse.equinox.launcher___.jar" file. Thanks for any help.
--- jon

Answer (score 1):

Solved!! "C:\Users\jon\.p2\pool\plugins\net.sourceforge.texlipse_1.5.0\texlipse.jar".
Inverse search works. 
This is for my machine --- yours might be different!
I found the location by looking around in the eclipse directory and found "java-oxygen\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.equnox.simpleconfigurator\bundlies.info"
which has a long list of plugins.  --- jon

Answer (score 1):

In common with most editors SumatraPDF is best **not** configured as DDE but use the much simpler reliable CLI mode thus for Eclipse with TeXlipse the inverse search is simply = `"drive:\path to editor\eclipse.exe" " %f:"%l` obviously you need to change drive:\path to your own and keep the " marks.

Equally the forward search is simplified to nothing in DDE fields (If eclipse pops up a DDE error, raise that issue with eclipse team. Were not using DDE)
You simply set up a new profile to the SumatraPDF.exe as per this screen shot the main difference is a very simple `-forward-search "%texfile" %line %file` this will go to any of the included source files from the one compiled pdf. In the screen shot its from the  included article to page 3 and back again (the page 2/3 is because were not in page mode)

[image]