# Question about viewer configuration texlipse

Tags: texlipse

I have had some trouble configuring TexLipse on Windows. At the moment I am in the stage that a pdf document is being built, but no viewer is started.

I read that the viewer has to be specified, configured, if you like.

I have no preference for any PDF viewer but I have Acrobat Reader and Foxit PDF installed.

I would like to see a screenshot of a viewer configuration from a working TexLipse installation on Windows.

update:

I have seen this question

[Restoring default viewer settings in texlipse](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/178911/restoring-default-viewer-settings-in-texlipse)

but that would require downloading yet another PDF viewer without knowing that it would work.

Comment: Did you follow the steps in the online manual? Especially [the part about setting up the application for the first time](http://texlipse.sourceforge.net/manual/configuration.html) and selecting the viewer? See picture: http://texlipse.sourceforge.net/manual/images/conf4.gif

Comment: Thanks for your comment; I will verify this and report.

Comment: In the meantime I am thrown back a few steps. Have to create a new Eclipse project and Github repository first.... - The "good side" of it all is that we are in lock down ( Netherlands ): what a waste of time for millions and millions.